# Learn from Other site

Tags: plugins

I am new bee and learning word press and visiting different sites to see their work & designs, is there any way that how do i know that what plugin, themes they used in their web site.

Answer (score 1):

You can also view source or use inspect element in your browser. From there, search for "theme" and you'll find the wp-content/themes/ folder and then the name of the theme right after it (if they're using WordPress).  Similar with plugins, you can usually find references to the plugin in the source code on the site.

As @rick mentioned, you can use some searches on Google, or using a site called https://builtwith.com and that'll usually give you a bunch of info. Normally not EVERY plugin is listed, but it'll give you a chunk to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the googles for 'what wordpress theme is that'. You will find several sites that will tell you that info.